# What are some sources on college life in the second half of the 19th century USA

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, book

Could someone please direct me towards books (diaries, memoirs...) on college life (particularly dental colleges) in the USA in the second half of the 19th century (particularly 1870s)? Thank you!